# Get notified when multiple AsyncHttpClient requests complete

Tags: android, loopj

I'm using Loopj's android asynchronous http client. 
What I have is a for loop which creates multiple asynchronous http requests to a web service.

Is there a way I'll get notified when all of them finish ?

Answer (score 1):

As http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ can be used in static way. 
What you can do is , whenever you create a request, you add to a static variable, and whenever you get response(include both scenario onsucess/onfailure, reduce the static variable by 1). 
When the variable is again 0, do your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via an event bus listener. In on end state of your request, you can send an event to all subscribers you want to notify. Check implementations for event buses below:

- http://square.github.io/otto/
- https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

But all this it depends on you code. if you know how many multiple requests will send then it's easy to subscribe on all events of each async request and you can check if all done. If you don't know the number of the requests before, then you can create a logic to keep the status of each request and then send the event to notify the subscriber you want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly what you want, however it might be a good solution for you. You can just use "get" property.
The description is:
"Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result."

And since you are using it in a loop, you propably want to add the result to a list or something.